# Briton vs briton vs British

Tags: nouns, adjectives

> 1. Two Briton rock musicians are visiting Japan.
> 2. Two briton rock musicians are visiting Japan. (Lowercase 'b').
> 3. Two British rock musicians are visiting Japan.

Out of the three, which are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[British](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/British) is an adjective, [Briton](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/briton) is a noun. The following are all correct:

> Two British rock musicians are visiting Japan.
>
> The two rock musicians visiting Japan are British.
>
> The two rock musicians visiting Japans are Britons.